# How to create search api with different datatype in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using this in my code and getting an error

```
const searchKey = req.params.key;
 const user = await User.find({
        '$or': [
            { name: { $regex: searchKey } },//Type String
            { phone: { $regex: searchKey } },  //Type Number
            { email: { $regex: searchKey } }//Type String
        ]
    });
```

Getting Error
"stack": "CastError: Cast to number failed for value "99" (type string)

API URL = http:localhost/search/abc
API URL = http:localhost/search/999

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the `phone` field is a number, but the `searchKey` variable is a string. When the `$regex` operator is used on a number field, the value being searched for must also be a number.

To fix the error, you can either convert the `searchKey` variable to a number before using it in the query, or you can modify the query to use the `$eq` operator instead of the `$regex` operator for the `phone` field.

To convert the `searchKey` variable to a number, you can use the `Number()` function:

```
const searchKey = Number(req.params.key);
```

To modify the query to use the `$eq` operator instead of the `$regex` operator for the phone field, you can change the following line:

```
{ phone: { $regex: searchKey } }
```

To this:

```
{ phone: { $eq: searchKey } }
```

The `$eq` operator will compare the value of the `phone` field to the value of the `searchKey` variable. If the values are equal, the document will be returned in the results.

Once you have made one of these changes, the error should be fixed.